# JS: I'm passing an array to a function and filtering and the array changes outside the function. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a `myFunction1` that gets a list of lists stored in the cache that is filtered based on the values of other cells to get a final list to populate a dropdown data validation. This happens in a loop because each cell is gonna have a different set of values in the data validation.

I realized after some time that when function2 is called, the `forEach`  function I use to filter the array of arrays into an array is actually modifying `myList` because in the next iteration the forEach filters the first character of each element in the list and in the next iteration it breaks because some elements were left undefined.

I'm confused as to why this happens, I know that in Python there is no variable declaration just a name pointing to something that's why a deep copy is necessary. This reminded me of that.

I found a work around by doing a dummy filter like this: `var newList = myList.filter(r => r[0]);`
But I can't figure out why `myList` was updated outside the scope of `myFunction2`. Below are my two functions as example.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var myList = getFromCache('myList');

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var a = sheet.getRange(i, 5);

    var b = "someVariable"

    if (b) {
      updateUnitsList(b, myList, a);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
function myFunction2(b, myList, a) {
  if (b === "any") {
    var newList = myList
    newList.forEach((r, index) => newList[index] = r[1]);
  } 

  // Rest of code

}
```

Comment: `newList = myList` does not make a copy of the original array.

Comment: When you do `newList = myList` you are making the variable "newList" _refer to_ the same array as "myList", you are not making a copy of the array. Anything you do that affects the contents of newList is affecting the underlying array memory that both variables share.

Comment: Not even when declared as a `var`? Anyway, I first was using `myList.forEach...` directly without variable assignment and the same was happening. What I don't understand is why myList in function1 is modified from the operations I do in function2

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope. It's how references/pointers work in any language. It just happens that in javascript you have no control of what is a references and what is a value. All arrays are references. So `newList = myList` means assign the address to the array `myList` to the variable `newList`. So both variables point to the same area of RAM

Comment: You can make a (shallow) clone before operating on the list by doing `let newList = [...myList];` or `let newList = myList.slice()` As slebetman noted, the difference between `var` and `let` is the _scope_ of the variable, not the ... "kind". https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/

Answer (score 3):

**Replace:**

```
var newList = myList
```

**with:**

```
let newList=myList.slice()
```

**or:**

```
let newList = [...myList]
```

to create a shallow clone of `myList`.

Right now, both `newList` and `myList` point to the same object.

Comment: The freecodecamp article [How to clone an array in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/) I cited earlier says both spread and slice create _shallow_ clones, not deep clones.

Comment: @StephenP feel free to edit the post. It is a wiki post so anyone can edit it. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's clear now. I'm starting on JS and had my mind closed on the scope of where the variable was defined.